# How to dock a sidebar created with Firefox WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've created a sidebar using Firefox WebExtensions, but I'd love to dock the sidebar to the bottom, I did search a lot, and couldn't find anything.

The code I used is this one:

Sidebar.js

```
var thisPanel = browser.extension.getURL("/this.html");
var thatPanel = browser.extension.getURL("/that.html");

function toggle(panel) {
  if (panel === thisPanel) {
    browser.sidebarAction.setPanel({panel: thatPanel});
  } else {
    browser.sidebarAction.setPanel({panel: thisPanel});
  }
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  browser.sidebarAction.getPanel({}).then(toggle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*Well, it's called a **side**bar..*

Quoting WebExtension [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/sidebar_action), emphasis mine:

> A sidebar is a pane that is displayed **at the left-hand side** of the browser window, next to the web page.

If you want something docked elsewhere, either you need to inject DOM into the page with content scripts (fragile), or write a [`devtools.panels` extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools.panels) and dock it within Dev Tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is limited by Webextension standards: you can't call user actions that awaiting promises, because this isn't considered as a "user action handler". Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/User_actions):

> Some WebExtension APIs perform functions that are generally performed as a result of a user action. [...] 
>   To follow the principle of "no surprises", APIs like this can only be called from inside the **handler for a user action**.

There is a good [workaround](https://github.com/Croydon/vertical-tabs-reloaded/issues/134#issuecomment-341889998) for some alike problems using `runtime.connect()`